# hide-show display multiple lines while collapsed

Tags: clojure, hideshow

Is it possible to have [hide-show](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hideshow.html) folding display multiple lines (probably 3) in the folded version? This would get us practically to having a [codox](https://github.com/weavejester/codox)-like view right inside a buffer.

What I'm trying to accomplish is using clojure-mode to display the function signature **and docstring**. AFAICT, `hs-toggle-hiding` (and `hs-hide-*` etc) always collapse to a single line. If hide-show isn't capable of this, do you know of another tool that could do the job?

Presently, a multi-line fn loses some key parts.

### Today

```
(defn foo
  "Does something really fancy, and there are. Maybe. Multiple. Sentences/lines. Here."
  [x y]
  (some code ,,,))
```

becomes:

```
(defn foo...)
```

which is informationally kinda useless.

### Goal

Instead, folds to:

```
(defn foo
  "Does something really fancy, and there are. Maybe. Multiple. Sentences/lines. Here."
  [x y] ...)
```

or maybe optimally:

```
(defn foo
  "Does something really fancy, and there are..." 
  [x y] ...)
```

### Attempts

I've tried setting things like this, but I still don't see that hide-show support multi-line display:

```
(setq hs-special-modes-alist '((clojure-mode "(defn [-a-z]+ \"[^\"]+\"" ")" ";; " nil nil)))
```

*(A workaround is to use `set-selective-display` with an argument of 3, but that only operates at a whole-buffer level, and shows other unwanted things.)*

Answer (score 0):

For Clojure, I'm now using `cider-browse-ns` as a compromise, which does a decent job of listing all the vars with their docstrings. It works in a `browse-ns` mode that offers:

```
RET     cider-browse-ns-operate-at-point
^       cider-browse-ns-all
d       cider-browse-ns-doc-at-point
n       next-line
p       previous-line
q       cider-popup-buffer-quit-function
s       cider-browse-ns-find-at-point
```

I found it more convenient if tweaked for an easy binding and assume we want the namespace I'm already visiting:

```
(key-chord-define-global "BG" (lambda () (interactive) (cider-browse-ns (cider-current-ns))))
```